# Reading a chart in English

Tags: phrasing

So the question says this graph shows the New Zealand population throughout the years, but when I add the percentages of the four examined age groups shown in the chart, I get more than 100%. Is there any misunderstanding here, or do they really phrase the question incorrectly in an IELTS test?

[image]

Comment: Yes the graph is nonsense.  It would be nonsense in any language, so this isn't a ELL question. An English test is not a good place to find population statistics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the graph would be the same in any language.

Comment: Is there any chance it's talking about the rate of growth in each group, not the proportion of the group?

Comment: It is more likely that the person who wrote the test just drew random lines.

Comment: For example, apparently there are no people in NZ who are between 45 and 65.

Comment: Why is the graph nonsense? I think you misunderstood it. It doesn't show the total population. And, the some age groups aren't included in the research.

Comment: Are you saying that in 1990,  70% of over sixty-five year-olds are from New Zealand? That is mathematically possible but obviously false (most old people in the world are not from New Zealand)  The graph is utter garbage.  Look at the irregular x-axis,  the missing groups, the nonsense forecasts for 2050 (25-37 year-olds will be extinct, as the population of children grows)  The graph is utter garbage.

Comment: @KenAdams Yes, the task description is possibly wrong, and the graph title might be correct, so it is the rate of growth of each group. You may infer that the proportion of children is increasing, that of old people >65 years is decreasing etc.

Comment: I think this graph shows that once they reach middle age New Zealanders lie about their age until they qualify for social security.

Comment: The number of old people isn't growing by 70% a year

Comment: The simple fact is that this was produced in the UK, and most people in the UK quit maths at age 16, are functionally innumerate, and don't have the maths skills to deal with percentages and graphs. The person who created this graph probably couldn't understand that anything was wrong. They just wanted to make a graph with some lines that go up and some that go down, with some dates in the past and some in the future and simply did not even think to check that the percentages add up to 100.